# Unexpected indexes behavior while attempting to add widget to kivy's GridLayout using coordinate axis

Tags: python, kivy

I am trying to write a piece that would add widgets that would add a `Label` widgets to a borders of x * y `GridLayout` with their texts equal range of `i` beginning with starting position and direction determined by user. For example, if we have `GridLayout` 3 x 3, `starting_position = [2, 1]` and `direction = 'anti-clockwise'`, we expect to get

```
3 2 1
4 * 0
5 6 7
```

Before I started, I have run the following code:

`for i in range(8):
    self.add_widget(Label(text=str(i)), index=i)`

so I learnt that indexes start at bottom left, and then go left to right, bottom to down.

Two main ideas in this are that

1) we transform coordinate list into one `int` to use as `index` argument in `add_widget`;

2) we use a function to calculate our next coordinates based on current ones and `direction`.

I have added the first one into the function of the second, so we have now this:

`def get_index(coordinates_list, direction):
    *function body*
    return index_as_one_integer`

Here's the full code:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.gridlayout import GridLayout
from kivy.uix.label import Label

x, y = 3, 3 # as an example
starting_position = [1, 0] 
direction = 'clockwise'

current_position_coordinates = starting_position
current_index = current_position_coordinates[0] * y + current_position_coordinates[1]

class Test(GridLayout):

    def get_index(self, coordinates_list, direction):
        return index_as_one_integer # I'm not including the function itself cause 1)it's relatively large # and 2)it has been proven (manually checked) to be working correctly for every case. See below for example

    def build(self):
        super().__init__(cols = x, rows = y)

        for i in range(8): # x * 2 + (y - 2) * 2
            self.add_widget(Label(text=str(i)), index=current_index)
            current_index = self.get_index(current_position_coordinates, direction)
            current_position_coordinates = [current_index % self.cols, int(current_index / self.cols)]

class Application(App):

    def build(self):
        return Test()


Application().run()
```

However, it results not in

```
3 4 5
2 * 6
1 0 7
```

but in

```
7 2 6
1 0 5
4 3 *
```

As for my `get_index` function, I printed out the index that it returns and then-current position coordinates. Here's the list for the example above:

```
7 [1, 0]
6 [0, 0]
3 [0, 1]
0 [0, 2]
1 [1, 2]
2 [2, 2]
5 [2, 1]
8 [2, 0]
```

So I suspect my general solution even though not perfect works as intended but it's Kivy's indexing system that's not that simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `index` parameter of `add_widget()` is poorly documented. The `add_widget(widget, index=i)` acts the same as `widget.children.insert(i, widget)`. The important key is that if `index` is greater than the number of children, then the widget is just appended to the list of children. You cannot insert widgets beyond the end of the list of children. So you will probably need to create your child widgets and add them to the `GridLayout` (with the default `index`) in the correct order to get your desired result.